# remove all the alphabets and special characters from a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a datframe like this

```
    A   B
0   0.0 sales oi 90,90
1   1.0 9.00
2   2.0 get it here999
3   3.0 sales for oi 90,90
4   4.0 this: 90,00,00
5   5.0 akjd : 90,000
```

I want my data frame like this

```
        A   B
0   0.0 9090
1   1.0 9
2   2.0 999
3   3.0 9090
4   4.0 900000
5   5.0 90000
```

Comment: This is not how this site works. You need to post specific questions and we will try our best to solve them, but your question is more like asking us to do the work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If want remove all non numeric values without dot use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex `[^\d.]` for any character if not decimal digit or `.`:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.replace(r'[^\d.]+', '')
print (df)
     A       B
0  0.0    9090
1  1.0    9.00
2  2.0     999
3  3.0    9090
4  4.0  900000
5  5.0   90000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular expression like this:

```
import re
re.sub("[^0-9]", "", "sales oi 90,90")
```

This will return:

```
9090
```

Using this, you can simply apply it to your dataframe using the lambda function:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda row: re.sub("[^0-9]", "", row))
```